# IllegalStateException: Only fullscreen opaque activities can request orientation

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have an activity that open from browser 
when Device is in Landscape get me below error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only fullscreen opaque activities can request orientation
```

Manifest

```
<activity android:name=".Activity.MyActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Theme_Slide"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="xxx"
                android:scheme="xxx" />
            <data
                android:host="xxx"
                android:scheme="xxx" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.Theme_Slide" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">false</item>
</style>
```

**UPDATE FIND SOLUTION**

In android Oreo (API 26) you can not change orientation for Activity that have below line in style

```
 <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

You have two way for solving this :

**1)** You can simply remove above line (or turn it to *false*) and your app works fine.

**2)** **Or** you can first **remove** below line from manifest for that activity

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Then you must **add** this line to java file

```
    //android O fix bug orientation
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
```

Comment: could we get an explananation as to why we can't change the orientaiton when `<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>`?