# Can't find exactly the cause of exception in play console crash report

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is the crash report shown in google play console:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.app.Activity.onCreate (Activity.java:1038)
  at com.tds.order.gui.changePassword.ChangePasswordActivity.onCreate (ChangePasswordActivity.java:39)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7183)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1220)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2910)
```

And this is onCreate method:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_change_password);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        presenter = new ChangePasswordPresenter(this, this); //context & interface
        bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    }
```

How can I know exactly what makes the app crash? knowing that this happens to specific devices so I cannot debug it and the activity's theme is Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.

Comment: check the statement at  `ChangePasswordActivity` line 39

Comment: not knowing what arguments `ChangePasswordPresenter` constructor takes, are you sure you have to pass to it `this` two times? maybe that's the mistake?

Comment: @qki first one is context second is the implemented interface, it works normally on other devices.

Comment: Possibly [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52422778/oreo-java-lang-illegalstateexception)

Comment: In fact, I think it is probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48787075/illegalstateexception-only-fullscreen-opaque-activities-can-request-orientation).